# jquery accordion on open / close panel execute other code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to executed other js code after the panel is opened and after it is closed. How to do this? I didn't find any events in the jq accordion documentation for that.

Comment: Always read the documentation first: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `.activate` event and observe what the parameters inside of the `UI` object look like:

```
activate: function( event, ui ) {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(ui.oldPanel)) {
        //was hidden previously, is visible now
    } else {
        //was visible previously, is hidden now
    }
}
```

[Here's the documentation on the even](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)

Comment: I've seen this, but didn't know how to use it in my case. In your code the ELSE is always executed no matter if I expand or collapse the panel.

Comment: ok, it's working now, I just changed for ui.oldPanel.context, but you at least gave the idea how to get this done instead of just posting that I can read documentation. Thanks for answer.